# SSIS - expression computation error when converting nchar empty string to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

I have a nchar(10) field in the database which I try to transform to int in the SSIS package.

The field contains 3 distinct values: empty string (`len(field)` in SSMS returns 0) and two numbers. In SSIS I have put the following expression on this field:

```
LEN(field) > 0 ? (DT_I4)field : (DT_I4)0
```

This, however fails with "DTS_E_EXPREVALSTATIC_COMPUTATIONFAILED" (-1073442796) error, but only for rows which contain empty string. To eliminate this issue, I used

```
LEN(TRIM(field)) > 0 ? (DT_I4)field : (DT_I4)0
```

That worked, but why is this the case? Why does it fail when len in SQL Server shows 0? Is this some problem with nchar/DT_WSTR?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `LEN()` in MS SQL and `LEN()` in SSIS Acts differently.

LEN (SSIS Expression):
Returns the number of characters in a character expression. If the string **includes** leading and trailing blanks, the function **includes** them in the count.

LEN (Transact-SQL):
Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, **excluding** trailing blanks.

```
Ref:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141797.aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329%28v=sql.110%29.aspx
```